# Is it possible to access directly a define with rain tpl

Tags: php, templates, constants

I need to access a DEFINE (defined in php) in a template managed by rain tpl.

```
define ('USECACHE',false);
```

I wonder if there is a way to access directly my define with rain tpl without assign it to template (like is done with globals variables POST, GET, SESSION, ... )

```
{$GLOBALS.variable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access `constants` by the following syntax

```
{#USECACHE#}
```